# I have a problem in my xsd file and couldnt find any other soultions. Can anyone have a look at my file?

Tags: xml, xsd

Cant specify the errors. Can anyone help me. I just started learning it and dont know much in details but here is my schema code.
When I tried to validate my XSD it gives the error

> S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_Website' Is Invalid.
> Element 'element' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>

<xs:element name="Music_store">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Details" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="Songs" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Details">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="Address" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="Contact" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:element ref="Website" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>                     
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
    
    <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="City" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="Street" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element ref="Postal_Code" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
                <xs:element ref="Zip_Code" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
        <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="Postal_Code" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="Zip_Code" type="xs:integer"/>
    
    <xs:element name="Contact">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element ref="Mobile" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
            <xs:element ref="Telephone" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
        
        <xs:element name="Mobile" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="Telephone" type="xs:integer"/>
    
    <xs:element name="Website">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="web" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="2"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
        <xs:element name="web" type="xs:url"/>

<xs:element name="Songs">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="Song" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
    
    <xs:element name="Song">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="director" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="producer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="artist" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="writers" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xs:element ref="genre" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="release_date" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute name="album" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:String"/>
        <xs:element name="director" type="xs:String"/>
        <xs:element name="producer" type="xs:String"/>
        <xs:element name="artist" type="xs:String"/>
        
        <xs:element name="writers">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:element ref="writer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        
            <xs:element name="writer" type="xs:string"/>
            
        <xs:element name="genre" type="xs:String"/> 
        <xs:element name="release_date" type="xs:String"/>
        
</xs:schema>
```

Here's my xml file.

```
 <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
    <Music_store
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="catalog_19031004.xsd" >
    > 
        <Details >
            <Name>Music Craft Nepal</Name>
            <Address>
                <City>Kathmandu,</City>
                <Street>Tankeshwor Marga,</Street>
                <Postal_Code>44600</Postal_Code>
            </Address>
            <Contact>
                <mobile>9841031342</mobile>
            </Contact>
        </Details>
        <Songs type="list">
        <title>Popular Songs</title>
            <Song id = "1" album="Kind of Blue">
                <name>Song:Blue in Green</name>
                <producer>Produced By:Irving Townsend</producer>
                <artist>By:Miles Davis</artist>
                <writers>
                    <writer>Miles Davis</writer>
                     <writer>Bill Evans</writer>
                </writers>
                <genre>Genre:Jazz</genre>
                <release_date>Released in:17 Aug,1959</release_date>
            </Song>
            <Song id="2">
                <name>Song:Sweet Child O' Mine</name>
                <producer>Produced By:Mike Clink</producer>
                <artist>By:Axl Rose</artist>
                <writers>
                    <writer>Guns N' Roses</writer>
                </writers>
                <genre>Genre:Rock</genre>
                <release_date>Released in:21 July,1987</release_date>
            </Song>
            <Song id="3" album="Fine line">
                <name>Song:Watermelon Sugar</name>
                <director>Directed By:Bradley &#38; Pablo</director>
                <producer>Produced By:Johnson Kid Harpoon</producer>
                <artist>By:Harry Styles</artist>
                <writers>
                    <writer>Harry Styles</writer>
                </writers>
                <genre>Genre:Pop</genre>
                <release_date>2019</release_date>
            </Song>
            <Song id="4" album="Traveller">
                <name>Song:Traveller</name>
                <producer>Produced By:Dave Cobb</producer>
                <artist>By:Chris Stapleton</artist>
                <writers>
                    <writer>Chris Stapleton</writer>
                </writers>
                <genre>Genre:Country Music</genre>
                <release_date>5 May,2015</release_date>
            </Song>
            <Song id="5">
                <name>Song:Scary Monsters and Nice Sprites</name>
                <producer>Skrillex</producer>
                <artist>By:Skrillex</artist>
                <writers>
                    <writer>Sonny Moore</writer>
                </writers>
                <genre>Genre:Dubstep</genre>
                <release_date>10 October,2010</release_date>
            </Song>
        </Songs>
    </Music_store>
```

Answer (score 0):

When I post your code into Oxygen, it highlights line 98, which reads

```
<xs:element ref="writer" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
```

and reports:

```
 Element <xs:element> cannot appear here: expected one of
 {Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}choice,
 Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}sequence,
 Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}assert,
 Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}openContent,     
    ... or nothing
```

So the first tip is: get yourself a decent XML IDE, and you will get much better diagnostics.

As the message explains, you can't have `xs:element` directly inside `xs:complexType`. You need an `xs:sequence` around the `xs:element`, even if there's only one element particle in the content model.

Comment: oh,ok thanks for your time. Its all sorted now.But why is it that we need to use the sequence tag even though we only have one child element?